# How to import a sass module containing variables from a different directory using @use?

Tags: css, import, sass

I have the following file structure (simplified) :

```
root
   scss
      abstracts
        _variables.scss
      base\ 
        _typography.scss
        _fonts
```

I can import any variable declared inside base via `@use 'fonts'` for instance and vice versa.
But whenever I am trying to access a sass stylesheet from another directory I get the following Error :

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
```

Weird is, my path is correct as VS-code allows me to follow the link.

```
@use '/root/scss/abstracts/variables';
```

I have tried dozens of different variations prior.

My sass is installed via path (standalone) recommended installation.

Basically I was trying to optimize my sass file structure and keep variables mixins and functions in a seperate folder.

I have also tried @import to no avail.

My actual project is separated via multiple _index.scss files and the imports down to main.scss work without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar structure, but I use **relative** paths instead of **absolute** paths.

```
css
    style.css
sass
    abstracts
        _functions.scss
        _mixins.scss
    base
        _typography.scss
    utility
    ...
    style.scss
```

In `style.scss` I import the `scss` files from the different directories, e.g.

```
@use 'utility/padding';
@use 'utility/border';
```

To import `scss` files between to directories, I do the following in `utility/_padding.scss`:

```
@use '../abstracts/functions';
```

So the `sass` command is something like this:
`sass sass\style.scss css\style.css`.

Comment: I could swear I tried the relative path before but anyhow it works. Mind buffling. I gotta accept this as answer nevertheless. Update : It works with `@import` but not with `@use`.

Comment: ````@use```` works fine for me. Also you should not longer use ````@import````. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Comment: It didn't work with the namespace created by SASS but when I define my own it does. Well aware @import is not being supported in the future. Docs are always the first place to look for answers. Either way you brought me on the right track and usually that's all I need. Cheers